# How do I specify a different Intent when debugging an Android app in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

When I click debug, the application is started with `Intent action=MAIN;`
I'd like to start it with `VIEW`, and specify a URI.

Answer (score 0):

Found it by browsing the Eclipse ADT source in the Adroid SDK.

start a shell on the target device:

$ adb shell

Then use the Android application manager:

## am -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT  -t "audio/x-mpegurl" -d "file:///mnt/sdcard/Audio/vocal.m3u"

This brings up the "complete action with" dialog.

Type 'am' to see all the options for specifying intents